# how can I make an object interface with "[ index: string ]:" work as a type that has defined properties that exist in the object?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an api endpoint returns something like:

```
{ 
  collection: [
    { attrs: { name: 'meower', ...etc } , isDog: false },
    { attrs: { name: 'purr-machine' ...etc }, isDog: false },
    { attrs: { name: 'sparky' ...etc }, isDog: true },
  ]
}
```

And I have an interface for this response that is generic and looks like:

```
interface ApiResponseItem {
  [ index: string ]: string | number | boolean | ApiResponseItem | Array<string | number | boolean>
}

export interface ApiResponse {
  [ index: string ]: string | number | boolean | ApiResponseItem | ApiResponseItem[]
}
```

I have a component that has:

```
interface Dog {
  name: string;
  ...etc
}

@Input() dog: Dog;
```

and the parent component does:

```
<ul>
<li *ngFor="let item of apiResponse.collection">
  <woofer [dog]="item.attributes" *ngIf="item.isDog">
  ...
```

I get:
`error TS2739: Type 'ApiResponseItem' is missing the following properties from type 'Dog': name`

.............  Can anyone please show me a way that I can get rid of this error without having to do something ridiculously dumb like:

```
<woofer [dog]="dogFor(item)" *ngIf="item.isDog">

...

dogFor: (item: ApiResponseItem) {
  return item.attributes as unknown as Dog;
}
```

Comment: Is this specific to react or angular something?  If so, please tag it as such. If not, please [edit] the code not to rely on `ngFor` , `@Input`, etc so that it's a [mre].

Comment: It is angular, but the problem is Typescript, NOT angular.

Comment: Sure, but now that it's tagged with angular you'll hopefully get people who know about it to help... those of us without angular in their environment or relevant knowledge of it can't easily reproduce the issue with this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A typeguard would probably work here. It forces TypeScript to recognize that item has a property `attribute` of type `Dog`, if the function returns true.

```
isDogResponseItem(item: ApiResponseItem): item is ApiResponseItem & { attributes: Dog } {
  return !!item.isDog;
}
```

```html
<li *ngFor="let item of apiResponse.collection">
  <woofer *ngIf="isDogResponseItem(item)" [dog]="item.attributes" >
      ...
```

Another way without a typeguard, if you think you know better than the TypeScript compiler, is to use `$any()` typecast function (casts values in template to `any`) available in Angular. Not recommended as it could lead to runtime errors.

```html
<ul>
<li *ngFor="let item of apiResponse.collection">
  <woofer [dog]="$any(item.attributes)" *ngIf="item.isDog">
  ...
```

Comment: and how would I handle calling functions instead of inputs?  For example, doing: `<button *ngIf="isDogResponseItem(item)" (click)="bark(item.attributes)">`  gives me  Argument of type 'ApiResponseItem' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Dog'.

Comment: I assume `bark()` takes an argument of `ApiResponseItem`, not `Dog`. Either change the argument type to `Dog`, or remove the typeguard in ngIf.

Comment: No, it `bark()` is expecting type `Dog` -- I wasn't doing exactly what my comment above showed, I was actually calling an instance method in the component class that was returning the result of `isDogResponseItem`, and apparently doing it that way breaks the type stuff...

Comment: I edited the typeguard above so that it will "remember" that the item passed is an ApiResponseItem, not sure if it will fix your issue.

Comment: yeah this is super weird, and seems to be very unreliable.  If I have the inverse: `isCatResponseItem(item: ApiResponseItem): item is ApiResponseItem & { attributes: Cat } { return !item.isDog; }` and try to use that in the same way (passing `items.attributes` to a function expecting a `Cat` type), I always get: `Argument of type 'ApiResponseItem' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Cat'` ... but if I pass it to a function expecting a `Dog` argument, it compiles fine-- even though that code would mean it's passing a Cat to a Dog method.............  arrgh TYPESCRIPT!!!!!!!!!!